# Trying to prevent modal close on button click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I'm working on a small project in ASP.NET MVC, and in one part I need help of javascript.
Acctually there is modal with three inputs, old password, new and confirm new password, 
and in case all fields are empty I need to prevent user from closing modal, I tried to solve it like this:

```
function comparePasswords(currentPassword) {

//Here I will loop throught all of my three inputs to check are they empty

var formInvalid = false;
    $('#allInputs input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
                formInvalid = true;
        }
    });

    if (formInvalid) {
        alert('One or more fields are empty.');
        $('#ChangePassword').modal({
         backdrop: 'static',
         keyboard: false  // I need to prevent user from clicking ESC or something 
        })
      }
 }
```

But I get following error (check the image):

[image: Chrome Debugger Console]

**EDIT:**

FULL CODE:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="UserPassword">Pw:</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { @class = "form-control custom-input", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#ChangePassword", ariaDescribedby = "basic-addon1" })
                </div>


                @*Modal for ChangePassword which is opening when user clicks on control above ^*@
                <div id="ChangePassword" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Updating password</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" id="allInputs">

                                @*Modal Old Password*@
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="UserPassword">Old password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control custom-input modal-trigger" value="Eldin123" name="oldPassword" id="OldPassword" data-toggle="modal">
                                </div>

                                @*Modal New Password*@
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="UserPassword">New password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control custom-input modal-trigger" value="" name="newPassword" id="NewPassword" data-toggle="modal">
                                </div>

                                @*Modal Repeat New Password*@
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="UserPassword">Confirm new password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control custom-input modal-trigger" value="" name="confirmPassword" id="ConfirmNewPassword" data-toggle="modal">
                                </div>


                                @*Modal - submit*@
                                <div class="confirm-login">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn custom-btn-big" onclick="comparePasswords();">NEXT</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>@*end of Modal for ChangePassword*@

                @*Confirm button*@
                <div class="confirm-login">
                    <button class="btn custom-btn-big" data-target="#">SAVE ALL CHANGES</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div> @*End of User / Administration*@
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>


            function fieldInvalid() {
                var formInvalid = false;
                $('#allInputs input').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() === '') {
                        formInvalid = true;
                        console.log(formInvalid);
                    }
                });
            }

            function passwordsInvalid() {
                var invalidPassword = true;
                var oldPw = $("#OldPassword").val();
                var newPw = $("#NewPassword").val();
                var confirmNewPw = $("#ConfirmNewPassword").val();
                if (oldPw != newPw) {
                    alert('Postojeći password nije ispravan.');
                }
                else if (oldPw != confirmNewPw) {
                    alert('Password koji ste unijeli se ne slaže.');
                }
                else {

                    invalidPassword = false;
                }

                return invalidPassword;
            }

            var comparePasswords = function () {
                if (fieldInvalid()) {
                    alert('One or more fields is empty.');
                }
                else {
                    if (!passwordsInvalid()) {
                        $("#ChangePassword").modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            }


    </script>

}
```

So when someone clicks on password input, modal will be opened, and from that modal after informations are there user should click on button "NEXT" and there is event onclick which is calling `comparePasswords` method.

Comment: Sounds like a issue with scripts loading in the correct order. Make sure jQuery comes before Bootstrap

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console?  Check the network tab for 404s/500s.

Comment: How are you opening the dialog in the first place?   Comments/Answers imply you're not getting a dialog at all, so it's not clear how you're trying to stop a dialog from closing if (according to the comments/answers) you don't have a dialog open to close.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm opening it when user clicks on some other label using data-target, then modal is shown and here is how: check for EDIT

Comment: You've included the *content* of the model, not the method used to open it.  Can you confirm that you get a valid `$.modal()` open before trying to close it?  What happens if you open the console and enter: `$("body").modal();`

Comment: @freedomn-m but when I click on that model, as you can see modal will be opened because of this line: data_target = "#ChangePassword", my modals  id is ChangePassword

Comment: @freedomn-m what do you think about trying to solve this by adding document.ready on my javascript? so I guess everything will load before I try my javascript method

Comment: There's no point putting it in doc.ready as the code that is failing is in `comparePasswords()` which, I'm assuming, is called when the dialog is already open.   Which leads to the question: exactly when are you calling `comparePasswords()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155077/discussion-between-roxypro-and-freedomn-m).

Comment: @freedomn-m there is a link for a room

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `bootstrap` library file.

Order of the file should be

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> Same Problem (missing bootstrap.js) http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/676/
>
> Problem resolved (by adding bootstrap.js) http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/677/

Hope this will help you.